# TradingView widget - Indicators customizations

Tags: javascript, widget, tradingview-api

Questions related to TradingView widget described and customizable through page https://www.tradingview.com/widget/ (not the 'Advanced Charts' widget!).

### Question 1

Does someone know how to set the 'Volume@tv-basicstudies' MA? With the '"studies_overrides"' one can set all the properties except the 'MA visible' one:

- "volume.volume ma.color": "#0000ff",
- "volume.volume ma.transparency": 45,
- "volume.volume ma.linewidth": 3,

Setting '"volume.volume ma.visible": true,' the error returned is 'Chart.Model.StudyPropertiesOverrider:Study plot does not have property 'visible'

It also doesn't work putting the command inside the "studies" section (no error is returned in this case):
"studies": [
{
"id":"Volume@tv-basicstudies",
"inputs": {
"volume.volume ma.visible": true,
}
}, ...

### Question 2

I saw somewhere (I lost the URL ...) different indicators available than the 'standard' ones '...@tv-basicstudies'.
For example: 'STD;EMA', 'STD;SMA', 'STD;MACD', 'STD;RSI', 'STD;Volume', 'STD;VWAP' (these are the ones I saw on that page or that I found trying).
They are different from the '...@tv-basicstudies' ones:

- EMA / SMA: a EMA/SMA-based moving average can be plotted
- MACD: more customizations available
- RSI: can show divergences, can show a RSI-based moving average (theoretically also RSI-based Bollinger Bands, but it doesn't seem to work ...)
- VWAP: can show up to 3 standard deviation/percentage-based bands around VWAP

Does someone know how to setup these indicators?

Thanks for any support.

Tried what available at page https://www.tradingview.com/widget/
Basic analysis of downloaded pages / resources through Developer Tools.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.